# How to get refreshed and new DOM element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using Web Application to automate using Javascript and selenium. There is a dropdown which has different portals and if I change the value from the dropdown entire page will get changed based on what portal we select. Say, Developer portal, Tester portal etc,.. but URL is same.

I can change the portal easily, but if I try to fetch the elements after changing the portal, I am getting the previous portal elements.

I am using JS with selenium,

```
String id = (String)jse.executeScript("var x = document.getElementsByTagName(\""+ tag +"\");var e=''; for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) { e+=x[i].innerText + \",\";if(x[i].innerText.trim()===\""+searchObject+"\"){x[i].click();}} return e;");
```

Note: If I use the refresh action, application navigates back to the previous portal(It is an application behavior).

Is there a way to get the elements?

Answer (score 0):

Use mutation observer for the above quest.

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');
// In your case this will body or the parent where you are adding elements

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
    });
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true }

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

The observer will notify you when some element added or any attribute changed or you have changed the text. If you want to observe only children just remove the other two.

Comment: Please do update your code in the question so that I can view what wrong is happening.